# Google sheets - Extract and SUM number in text function doesnt work if there is " . " next to number

Tags: regex, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, substitution

I have this function

```
=SUM(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2; "[^\d\.]+"; "|"); "|"))
```

and in A2 i have

> The shirt costs 20 euros and the jeans costs 30

So what the function does is to sum the 2 numbers contained in the above text. So it returns 50.

But the problem is that, if in A2 i have the same text but with a dot . at the end:

> The shirt costs 20 euros and the jeans costs 30.

It doesnt sum up the 2 numbers and it only returns **20**. I think that it only recognizes 20 as a number and not 30???

SAME thing happens if the dot . is in the start of the number:

> The shirt costs 20 euros and the jeans costs .30

It returns **20** again.

So I want the function to return **50** again.

I am a begginer on google sheets so i know that it might be very simple to fix, but my knowledge is still very restricted.

Can someone edit my function and paste it in the answers? Thanks.

Comment: Interestingly, your formula works for me. I get the result `50` whether a `.` exists or not. In fact, using your formula with the text "The shirt costs 20.13 euros and the jeans costs 30.45", I get the result `50.58`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this does not work for you:

[image]

try:

```
=SUM(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(A2, ".", ","), "[^\d\.]+", "|"), "|"))
```